# redux connect hides the JSDoc of basic component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jsdoc, higher-order-components

I have *some* component for which I have written some JSDOC:

```
/**
 * random jsdoc
 */
const Test = () => {
  return;
}
```

Now I can see this JSDOC wherever I use this component in a project (using JSDOC supported editor, of course).

As soon as this Test component gets connected to redux store, this JSDOC goes away. I understand that this is cause it creates a higher order component, which is different than the actual component. It's essentially the same component conceptually & we would want to express the details using JSDOC. Is there a way to propagate the JSDOC after using a Higher Order Component?

Comment: What if you add the jsdoc to the connected component?

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that your `Duck` is still a `Duck` (if only functionally), then you can tell your JSDocs parser that by casting the returned object as a `Duck`.

```
/**
 * I'm a Duck and I go "Quack!" (by default).
 */
class Duck {
  constructor () {
    this.quack = "Quack!";
  }
}

const duck = new Duck();
const newDuck = /** @type {Duck} */ (duckModifyingMiddleware(duck));
console.log(newDuck.quack, newDuck.quack, newDuck.quack);
```

If there's any chance that `duckModifyingMiddleware` will return something that isn't type-safe with `Duck`, you should handle this differently, such as checking the object's type manually for an indicator;

```
const duck = new Duck();
let newDuck = (duckModifyingMiddleware(duck);
if (newDuck.quack) {
  newDuck = /** @type {Duck} */ (newDuck);
  console.log(newDuck.quack, newDuck.quack, newDuck.quack);
} else {
  console.log('It did not look like a duck, it did not quack like a duck');
}
```